# How can I dynamically assign a database path in Express.js based on login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a backend service that I would like to use as a single point of entry for my web application, and dynamically assign a database path based on the user login. 
I realize that this is not a scalable solution. I intend to use it during a testing period with several clients (accessing the ALPHA database), and also setting up a demo (accessing the SAND database).
I have the following module that I have written as a simple test to see if the login is for the demo user, all other logins will go to the other resource:

`config.js`

```
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();

module.exports.dbPath = function  (login){
    console.log('login - ', login);
    if (login === 'demo@mysite.com'){
        return process.env.DB_SAND;
    } else {
        return process.env.DB_ALPHA;
    }
};
```

My question is, how can I manage each unique login and assign a globally accessible reference for that session to direct each user session consistently to the correct database?
Am I overcomplicating this? If there is a different approach that would be a better practice I would welcome a suggestion in another direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use it as a middleware, and attach it to the `req` object for each user, something similar this:

```
module.exports = {
    dbPath: function(req, res, next){
       var login = req.body.login;
       console.log('login - ', login);
       if (login === 'demo@mysite.com'){
          req.dbPath = 'DB_SAND';
       } else {
          req.dbPath = 'DB_ALPHA';
       }
       next();
    }
};
```

Comment: This seems reasonable for the login, but what is the approach for subsequent calls? Would it be secure to create a private object in this module that held a k:v pair for each login, with the key being the session token and the value being the DB path? I want to make sure that I don't inadvertently create a security hole.

Comment: I don't see how a k:v pair on the `req` object is a security hole. (Don't do it on the `res` object).